# very low fps cs go nvidia gt 740m

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games, framerate

I have Nvidia 384 installed, and I get 30~40 fps in CSGO, which is the only game that I've tried

on Windows 10, I get up to 100~120 fps on high settings, but on Linux, I get 40 tops

EDIT: anybody ?
EDIT: comeon guys no solution ?

Comment: What is the output of command `glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering"` ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz direct rendering: Yes